# What can cause app Interaction to stop but animations to still happen

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, nsurlrequest

I have an app that seems to have a UI crash where the user cannot control the application anymore... I have a spinning UIActivity view still spinning on screen so that makes me think that the thread is still running but for some reason the users touch events are not being registered?

This occurs randomly during sending a url request on a background thread and then returning the result via a block to the foreground thread using GCD... What can cause this? How can i debug this issue as everything else in the app occurs as normal and my app output continues in the debugger as if nothing is wrong...

Comment: make sure that all user interface changes are happening on main thread

Comment: Can a change from the BG thread cause this? I am fairly certain they are all in the UI thread but i will check :)

Comment: I just tried updating some ui from a background thread and nothing bad happened? Are you sure this could have the effect i am experiencing?

Comment: Updating UI from background thread can lead to various issues, usually crashes. This case looks like a deadlock of the main thread. Analyse your GCD code to solve it or add the code if you need help.

Comment: I have a feeling that the main thread might be getting updated twice at the same time? Would this cause an issue?